# How to print code output cleanly? Java Help: Scanner, PrintWriter, FileReader

Tags: java

Write a Java program to demonstrate file handling using Scanner, FileReader and PrintWriter classes. You will also make use of more advanced parsing techniques. You will use the split() method of the String to assist you in parsing.

You will open the file provided in args[0] for reading and the file provided in args[1] for writing. Read complete lines from the file one at a time until EOF.

Each line in the file will have the following format:

name:curriculum:gradyear:ssn:dob The information you read from the input file will be reformatted in the following form:

Student Name SSN DOB Curr Grad Yr

When I compile and run it, it prints out the first line fine then seems to put everything else on a new line and repeat itself. I was trying to get the header and lines String to print only once and have the rest follow accordingly.
The current code at the moment is..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class D2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String line, parts[];
int x;
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("d2.dat"));
PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

while(infile.hasNext()) {

  line = infile.nextLine();
  parts = line.split(":");
  for (x = 0; x < parts.length; x++)
    outfile.println(parts[x]);
  String ssn = parts[3]; String f, m, l;

  f = ssn.substring(0,3);
  m = ssn.substring(3,5);
  l = ssn.substring(5);

  String stringssn = f + "-" + m + "-" + l;

  String header =("Student Name                     SSN            DOB                    Curr       Grad Yr");
  String lines = ("------------                     ---            ---                    ----       -------");

  String data = (parts[0] + "                   " + stringssn + "     " + parts[4] +
                 "              " + parts [1] + "         " + parts[2]);


   System.out.println(header + "\n" + lines + "\n" + data);  
} 
outfile.close();
infile.close();
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample output for both expected and actual to provide clarity on:

"When I compile and run it, it prints out the first line fine then seems to put everything else on a new line and repeat itself. I was trying to get the header and lines String to print only once and have the rest follow accordingly"

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the output https://i.gyazo.com/58b01492013a3849ea09e9521a4c6834.png

Comment: *"I was trying to get the header and lines String to print only once"* Then move the printing of them **outside the loop**. --- Also remove the `for (x = ...` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to format console output like this using tab characters `"/t"` as opposed to spaces which you're using. This will help a lot with readability of your code as well.

---

To solve your issue with the headings, you simply need to take that code out of your while loop, so before entering the loop, do something like the following:

```java
if(infile.hasNext()) {
  // print headings
} else {
  // handle error case of !hasNext()
  outfile.close();
  infile.close();
  // exit execution
}
```

*the above is if you prefer early return over nested if/else execution, but wrapping your whole while loop in the above if statement would work as well*

---

If you really want to make things nice, there's always breaking your lines out into a string array, calculating the max string length for each "column" you're trying to display, and padding each string line with extra spaces programmatically to get a well formatted table.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the output https://i.gyazo.com/58b01492013a3849ea09e9521a4c6834.png

Answer (score 0):

You might also try looking at String.format.

As a starter, you could replace this:

```java
String data = (parts[0] + "                   " + stringssn + "     " + parts[4] +
                 "              " + parts [1] + "         " + parts[2]);
```

With something like this:

```java
String data = String.format("%-40s%-20s%-40s%-20s%s", parts[0], stringssn, parts[4], parts[1], parts[2])
```

Which means format the string with 5 fields. the first will take a string that it will left justify in a field 40 characters wide (you will need to adjust the 40 to get it to line up the next field. The second is also a string which will be left justified in a field 20 characters wide and so on.

You can also get it to format other datatypes such as Integers or doubles etc.

Here is the documentation for [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and the details of the types of fields you can put in the [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

I am not sure what you mean about the header, but usually you want to print that only once at the top of the output. The solution to that is simple, move the printing of the header to just before you start the loop. But again I am not sure that is what you mean as that seems pretty obvious.